# JSON or CSV from list in python

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, list

So I have a code that converts my category tree to a list and I wanted to convert it to CSV/json. Each item on list can have more ids as shown below.

```
    def paths(tree):
        tree_name = next(iter(tree.keys()))
        if tree_name == 'children': 
            for child in tree['children']:
                for descendant in paths(child):
                    yield (tree['id'],) + descendant
        else:
            yield (tree['id'],)
    
    
    pprint.pprint(list(paths(tree)))
```

**Output**

```
[(461123, 1010022280, 10222044, 2222871,2222890),
(461123, 129893, 119894, 1110100250),
(461123, 98943, 944894, 9893445),
(461123, 9844495)]
```

Is there any way I can improve my code or have another code that converts list to json that looks below output?

```
Output should look like this
{
   {
     "column1": "462312",
     "column2": "1010022280",
     "column3": "10222044",
     "column4": "2222871", 
     "column5": "2222890"
    },
    {
     "column1": "461123",
     "column2": "129893",
     "column3": "119894",
     "column4": "1110100250"
    }
  and so on... 
}
```

if csv should look like this. ** Can be up to column 10

| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 461123 | 129893 | 119894 | 1110100250 |
| 461123 | 129893 | 119894 |  |

Answer (score 0):

Following is the code to convert list of tuple to a list of dict which you can convert to json and the second function turns the data to a csv

```py
data = [(461123, 1010022280, 10222044, 2222871,2222890),
(461123, 129893, 119894, 1110100250),
(461123, 98943, 944894, 9893445),
(461123, 9844495)]

def convert_to_list_of_dicts(data):
    output_list = []
    for i in data:
        data_dict = {}
        for count,j in enumerate(i) :
            data_dict["column" + str(count+1)] = j
        output_list.append(data_dict)
    return output_list

# print(convert_to_list_of_dicts(data))

def convert_to_csv(data):
    max_column_num = 0
    for i in data:
        if len(i) > max_column_num:
            max_column_num = len(i)
    columns = ["column" + str(i+1) for i in range(max_column_num)]
    newdata = [tuple(columns)]
    for tup in data:
        newdata.append(tup)
    with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerows(newdata)

# convert_to_csv(data)
```